# Is there any way to keep prepared statements after commit in MyBatis?

Tags: java, transactions, mybatis

I use ReuseExecutor to keep prepared statements in one session, I also want to commit data sometime but keep prepared statements, as they are limited in number, and recreating them will significantly decrease productivity.

Unfortunately, in BaseExecutor(parent of ReuseExecutor) method flushStatements() is called on every commit, this means the statements are recreated again each time.

Is there any way to avoid flushStatements() on commit in MyBatis?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write plugin that would intercept call to Executor's flushStatements() method

[Configuration - plugins](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#plugins)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have tried this. Unfortunately flushStatements is not intercepted when it's called from commit method of executor.